# Silverlight Line shape with image on top of it

Tags: c#, silverlight-3.0, windows-phone-7

Is it possible to keep a skin on a Line in Silverlight. I have a Line shape, and an image file of a cool looking line Is it possible to keep this image on top of the Line where ever I draw?

Comment: I'm not clear about what you're trying to do. Can you please expand your explanation. Maybe include images of what you're trying to achieve. Plus add details of what you've tried.

Comment: I want to have some glow effect on a Line element.

Comment: I have a image of a line with glow.Is it possible to keep this image as a content or Fill to a Line element?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have an image always appear in the same position behind a line which you draw, you could just absolutely position both controls so they appear on top of each other.